# How to Filter Instances by Checking for a String in the Instance Name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am writing a python script to retrieve a list of instances that were incorrectly tagged. I need to filter by checked if a specific string exists in the name.

What is the best way to do this?

I was going to use describe_instances and use the tag filter (where the key is 'Name') but that filter requires that I provide the full value of the tag (i.e. the instance name) but I need to be able to search using a subset of the name.

Can this be done using the client?

Answer (score 1):

For whoever is reading this, you can do what John Rotenstein suggested in his answer, or, you can alternatively use the wildcard character '*' in the tag name, so your filter will be something like:

```
filters = [{'Name':'tag:Name', 'Values':['string*']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to call `describe_instances()` without a filter, then just loop through the results and perform your own filtering & fixup logic in Python.

General logic would be:

```
Create EC2 client
Call describe_instances
Loop through results['Reservations']['Instances']:
  Loop through instance['Tags']:
    if Key == 'Name' and "bad-string" in Value:
      Fix tag
```

If you have more than 1000 instances, you'll have to re-call `describe-instances()` with `NextToken`.

Comment: Thanks John! Yes this would work, but in my case I have a huge number of instances (more than 15k) so this would be not as efficient. I posted another solution below after doing some research that I think would work very well too, using filters and using the wildcard character '*'.

Answer (score 0):

The complete code to get a working snippet is:

```
CREDENTIAL = 'default'
REGION = 'eu-west-1'
INSTANCE_NAME = 'my_instance_name'
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=CREDENTIAL)
client = session.client('ec2', REGION)

custom_filter = [{
    'Name': 'tag:Name',
    'Values': [INSTANCE_NAME]
}]
response = client.describe_instances(Filters=custom_filter)
# example to get the state
print(response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['State'])
```

And if you want to dump it to a file:

```
import json
response_json = json.loads(json.dumps(response, default=str))
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(response_json, f, ensure_ascii=True, indent=2)
```